# Django. RSS feed

Tags: django, rss

I use standart django RSS:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed

class RSSFeed(Feed):
    title = "MyBlog"
link = "/news/"
description = "Last news:"
item_link=link

    def items(self):
        return BlogPost.objects.all()[:10]

    def item_title(self, item): 
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.description
```

urls:

```
(r'^feed/$', RSSFeed()),
```

As result I get http://mysite.com/news/ for each post. How can I make unique link for each post?

Posts have own urls:

```
url(r'^news/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', view_post, name='view_blog_post'),
```

view:

```
def view_post(request, slug):
return render_to_response('post.html', {
    'post': get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug),
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

In news models write the,

def get_absolute_url() method, which return the url of the each article